# How do I access a mounted partition on a bootable usb

Tags: partitioning, live-usb

I used echer to install the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS version of Ubuntu. the 25 gb partition shows up in discs but not in files. The partition type is Linux and is mounted. Can’t find any way to save to it or read it all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks
Edit the first version on this page https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Hello First thing is you need to give an actual version. Latest is not a version and there are at least 2 that can be called latest.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop this one the first one on the page

Comment: Is the drive encrypted?

Comment: I have updated the version in your question for clarity as you said, https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop <- first page

Comment: You should have said the version not tell me to go look at a link. Any question needs the version stated in it.

Comment: Where is your usb mounted and what happens if you navigate to that location? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Open Disks, highlight the drive on the left side, highlight the partition on the right side, click the little triangle at the bottom and it should turn to square. Partition should then be visible in Files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fdisk installed use `fdisk` to list all your drives and partitions

```
fdisk -l
```

Use `mount` to mount your device.

```
 sudo mount -t ext4 DEVICE_NAME DIRECTORY
```

Example

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media
```

Usually when mounting a device with a common file system such as ext4 or xfs the mount command will auto-detect the file system type. However, some file systems are not recognized and need to be explicitly specified.

Use the -t option to specify the file system type

Incase of conflicts, you can use `dmsetup` to remove mounted partitions

To remove a single device use:

```
dmsetup remove /dev/your-device
```

To remove all use:

```
dmsetup remove_all
```

Then try again mounting you partition.

You can also mount your partition using the `disks` app in your applications